# Replacing content between two tags first occurence

Tags: replace, sed, tags

I am trying to replace some content between tags with the following expression

```
sed -i -e ':a;N;$!ba' -e 's#<a href="/" class="logo">.*</a>#<a href="/" class="logo">{{{ svg "/myLogo.svg" 100 100 }}} <img src="/logo.png"></a>#' $file
```

The problem I am facing is I apply it to a text like:

```html
<div class="bar">
    <a href="/" class="logo">
        <svg viewBox="13.195 149.965 803 267.334">
                <path fill="#6A5B53" d="M233.773,218.468l-6.19,65.33c-3.429-29.427-19.904-64.188-41.427-82.473
                    c0.667-1.048-0.381-8,0.476-8.856L266.773,218.468z"/>
                <path fill="#FFC3B7" d="M260.583,285.894c0.476-63.331-51.236-116.662-115.424-116.377/>
     </svg>
                <image src="/logo.jpg">          </svg>
    </a>

    <ul class="newmenu"><li><a href="/char" title="">Char</a></li>
<li><a href="/price" title="">Price</a></li>
<li><a href="/account" title="">Account</a></li>
<li><a href="/login" title="">Login</a></li>
</ul>    <div class="log">.....
```

So after I execute it, the script replaces it until the last `</a>` instead of replacing up to the first `</a>`.

How can I prevent from replacing all the way up to the last tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.*` in `...class="logo">.*</a>` is greedy and match any characters until last `</a>` found.

If your opening and closing `a` tags are on different lines, you can use the sed `c`  command :

```
sed  -i -e '/<a href="\/" class="logo">/,/<\/a>/ c\
<a href="/" class="logo">{{{ svg "/myLogo.svg" 100 100 }}} <img src="/logo.png"></a>
' file
```

**Explanation :**

- `/<a href="\/" class="logo">/,/<\/a>/` : this address range match all lines from `/<a href="\/" class="logo">/` to next `/<\/a>/`
- `c\` : *change* command, to replace matching lines with following text (`\` is for starting the replacement with a newline)
- following the `c`command is the substitution text. If you want to replace with multiple lines, you must add a trailing `\` to each line (except the last one).

To illustrate this last point :

```
sed -e '/fromtext/,/totext/ c\
add line 1\
add line 2\
addline 3
' file
```

In some sed versions, you can write your substitution text on the same line after the `c` as (eg `sed '/fromtext/ c newtext' file`).

Comment: Great solution, thank you very much. If you have some time could you explain the way in which you use c\ here, the documentation is not so clear.